# can the continuous be used for something that I am angry about, that happened once?

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

One of the uses of the present perfect is to express a complain or criticism. It is also used if something has been happening regularly. The present perfect is used if something has happened once or a number of times.

My question is: If something happened once, but I am angry about it, can I use the present perfect continuous? For example: someone has urinated in my garden when drunk at a party. Can I say: "Have you been urinating in my garden?".

I have a feeling that if I use the present perfect simple, it doesn't sound as irritated or cross.

Comment: The reason *present perfect simple doesn't sound as irritated or cross* is because Present Perfect implies *strong connection to time of utterance*. So *Have you been smoking cannabis?* probably implies *I can smell it* or *You look stoned* (short-term aftereffects of a one-off action; were you smoking within the last few hours?). But a doctor checking you out for possible Alzheimer's might pose exactly the same question to ask if you've indulged repeatedly over months / years (even if not in the past few *days*). Context often makes a big difference.

Comment: (In your context, part of that "strong connection" is the fact that ***you're still angry***.)

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica I have seen an example where present perfect simple is used when someone finds urine in the bathtub and ask their spouse if they have urinated in the bathtub. How would you explain the use of the present perfect simple in that case? they are simply asking and are not angry, perhaps?

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica "because present perfect implies strong connection to time of utterance" do you mean the present perfect continuous?

Comment: That "relevance to time of utterance" could be ***any*** "current emotional reaction", not just anger. So *Have you been working out?* might imply *I'm [right now] impressed by your muscular physique* without necessarily implying anything so recent as *...working out in the past few hours or days*. And if we assign such connotations to Present Perfect, I see no reason why that should be qualified by the caveat *...but not with **continuous** verb forms*.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica sorry, I don't understand the last sentence: I see no reason why that should be qualified by the caveat ...but not with continuous verb forms. What does that mean?

Comment: I mean you should just take my initial assertion *(Present Perfect implies strong connection to time of utterance)* at face value, without "special exceptions". That's to say you should assume it applies *by default* (regardless of whether it's a ***continuous*** Past Perfect form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase your question any way you like. Whether it's appropriate really depends on the context.

Your options are:

> Did you urinate in my garden (at the party)?

implies on a particular occasion.

> Have you urinated in my garden?

implies at any time?

> Have you been urinating in my garden?

is more accusatory, even if it refers to just a single occasion. It's the kind of question that is put to people who may have reverted to bad habits, as in:

> Have you been drinking/smoking/taking drugs (again)?

In short, you can certainly phrase it that way. How cross it sounds is likely to depend more on the manner in which you ask it and your tone than exactly how you phrase it.

Comment: so the continuous can be used for a single occasion? Does the present perfect sound less accusatory? –

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are angry or not doesn't really matter.  The only question is whether you view it as happening at single point in time, or a continuous period in time.

Clearly for urinating doesn't happen in an instant, so it is possible to use a continuous tense, but it is not required.  If it is relatively recent you're more likely to use a continuous tense.

So in the situation that you describe, it is correct to say:

> Did you urinate ...
>
> Were you urinating ...
>
> Have you been urinating...

But it would be as correct to say

> Have you been eating in my garden

When you are not angry at all.

If this is a real situation, the use of the slightly medical sounding word "urinate" is a little over-formal.  If you want to sound angry.

> What the hell!? Were you pissing in my *garden*. Get the f*** out of my house! Before I call the police.

That is angry!  Is this a real situation that you have been in?

Comment: Do you mean : single point in time = did you urinate and continuous period in time = were you urinating or have you been urinating?

Comment: Is "have you urinated in my garden?" correct as well? You didn't mention that one. Also, what do you mean by a continuous period? Meaning lasting for a while, or happening more than once? I want to refer to a single occasion.

Comment: That is correct grammar too. It is basically a question of "Do you have the experience of urination in my garden.  Depending on the context it could sound like an invite:  "Have you urinated in my garden? No!? Oh you must, it's such fun!"  But this question is really about "anger" and can you imply anger by the use of perfect continuous.

Comment: You can ask that, and you can ask did you fart.  Here is the thing: perfect tenses have a range of uses.  They generally relate past actions to present states.  So they can be used to ask about things that have happened recently (so the effects linger in the present) or they can ask about experiences.  So "Have you farted"  pragmatically can't mean "Have you ever farted" because everybody has.  It must mean "Have you farted recently?" It is probably not even really a question, but a rhetorical device meaning "I blame you for farting".  You always understand in context.

Comment: So if there is evidence of urination in my garden I can ask the person: "Have you urinated in my garden?" meaning recently?

Comment: Yes, you can ask that.

Comment: So it doesn't necessarily always mean "Have you ever urinated in my garden?"

Comment: I feel I'm going around in circles.  No context is important.

Comment: @ James K You probably mean context is important, you forgot the comma after "No".